# SVN. Слияние двух branch в третий

Tags: svn, git-merge

Возникла необходимость слить несколько веток разработок между собой. Т.е. на данный момент следующая структура:

```
- trunk
- branches
 -- b1 (from trunk)
 -- b2 (from trunk)
 -- b3 (from trunk)
```

Необходимо создать `b4`, в которую войдут изменения из `b1`, `b2`, `b3`, но при этом эти изменения не должны попасть в `trunk`.

Я попытался сделать `b4` из `trunk`, потом `b4` смержить с `b1` (merge two different trees), но в итоге SVN не нашел изменений.

Есть ли какие-то способы решения моей проблемы?

Comment: Раз не видит, может их и нет?

Comment: Изменения есть, поэтому и уточняю.